# drupal translate module issue, assign custom fields to autotranslate

Tags: drupal, administration, translate, action

Drupal:Can I assign custom fields to autotranslate them when I create a  new article?
By default it creates and translates the Title and Body field, but I have several more depending on the content types. (This is set on actions)
I didn't quite know how to add more fields to translate

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what those other fields are. Would the be something that is created using CCK or views?

Drupal uses the function `t(...)` to translate strings, if you want that functionality you need to wrap your text in that.

[More info about t() and how it works.](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6) (Drupal 6)
[More info about the Localization API](http://drupal.org/node/322729) ([PDF cheat sheet](http://drupal.org/files/Drupal6TranslationCheatSheet.pdf))

**UPDATE**

Just found a link to what might be more suitable for your needs:
Drupal.org > [Translating Content in Drupal](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/translation)

Comment: yes, I have some fields created with CCK , for example I have some articles about recepies and apart from title, and body I have Ingredients (text fields) and elaboration (textarea). I'm using v6. Note that the other content types don't have this particularity and work just fine.. title and body are created and translated automaticaly in spanish when I create an english article

Comment: I would take a close look at the Localization API and learn more about how Drupal does translation. Chances are that if you want the entire site to be multi-lingual then you would need a solid understanding of the basic workings of how Drupal does translation. Best of luck :) and if you found my input helpful please consider giving a vote.